# How to overlay one div on top of another?

Tags: html, css, navbar, overlay

I'm currently working on a landing page for a website. I want the navigation menu to have a shadow blur, just like this (https://ibb.co/9ZkJ8tD).

The problem is, I haven't been able to figure out how to execute that. I tried creating a container div with two separate divs inside (the mask div and the actual div). I then had the two divs mirror each other, in specs and position. This is my CSS so far (I create borders around each element so I can see them in live server):

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Distinctive Brokers</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-container">
                <ul id = "menu" >
                    <li><a href = "#listings">Listings</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="mask">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .mask
    {
        border: 2px solid gold;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #menu{

        border: 2px solid magenta;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: space-between;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    li{
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

This is what it looks like at the moment (https://ibb.co/xf80vFt).

What would be the simplest method to create the navigation bar? I'm relatively new to web development so I would to avoid anything with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)` to have the visibility effect. You can change the `a` number according to your liking of the visibility. `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)` will go full white while `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` will go full transparent.

Comment: you don't need 2 div for this.